# Changing Open Help Search Preferences

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've fount a way to change **Open Help Search** Preferences through code by:

```
IEclipsePreferences pref = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode(HelpBasePlugin.PLUGIN_ID);

pref.put(IHelpBaseConstants.P_KEY_SEARCH_FROM_BROWSER, "whatever");
//apparently the second String is unimportant as it will always change "Open Help Search" to "In the dynamic help view"
```

Anyway, now I want to change **Open Help Search** back to *In a browser*

However, looking through IHelpBaseConstants, I see there are only values and keys for **Open help view documents**.

Are there other classes, API's or things I might have missed out on that can change Help Preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This preference is a Boolean value so you should be using:

```
pref.putBoolean(IHelpBaseConstants.P_KEY_SEARCH_FROM_BROWSER, true/false);
```

An arbitrary value appears to work because the `getBoolean` code uses:

```
Boolean.valueOf(result).booleanValue();
```

to convert the preference string. This treats anything other than the string `true` as being false.

Comment: How am I always missing out on these? Thanks a lot! It worked, and thanks to you I figured how the rest of them work.